# How to mark a centroid (=mean) for each clustering

Tags: data

I have a huge dataset in Txt file and I did clustering by using Kmean Method, but I could not mark the centroid for each clustering.

If you know the code for that, please reply to this post,

Thank You all,

Comment: What have you tried?  (Are you using *Mathematica*?  I ask because there's nothing in this question or your other question today that suggests *Mathematica* is involved.)

Comment: I tried to use Mathematica for programming.

Comment: Data = Import[
   "/Mathematica -Data \
Mining/random_data.txt", "Data"]; FindClusters[Data, 5, Method -> "KMeans"]; ListPlot[m]

Comment: You increase your chances of getting an answer by providing accessible example data and a bit of code to start with. Creating random data on the fly is always prefered over uploading the file somewhere and posting the link here, **but not giving any data at all is usually seen as low effort on this site**. Anyways, `Mean /@ m` probably does what you are asking for; it recturns the means of the point clouds.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you find this useful...

```
Data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];
m = FindClusters[Data, 5, Method -> "KMeans"];
Show[
 VoronoiMesh[Mean /@ m, Transpose[List @@ BoundingRegion[Data]]],
 ListPlot[m, PlotRange -> List @@ BoundingRegion[Data]],
 ListPlot[Partition[Mean /@ m, 1]]
 ]
```

[image]